# How can I combine code

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote a program, but I think not good what I use one code two times.

Problematic place is here:

```
if (2 * cell_price > large_cell_price) {
    for (int i = 0; i < parquet.size(); ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < parquet[i].size(); ++j) {
        if (parquet[i][j] == '*') {
          if (j + 1 < parquet[i].size() && parquet[i][j + 1] == '*') {
            j++;
            sum += large_cell_price;
          } else {
            sum += cell_price;
          }
       }
     }
   }
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < parquet.size(); ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < parquet[i].size(); ++j) {
        if (parquet[i][j] == '*') {
          sum += cell_price;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I do loop two times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parquet.size(); ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < parquet[i].size(); ++j) {
```

And I can't combine it. How I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parquet.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < parquet[i].size(); ++j) {
        if (parquet[i][j] == '*') {
           if (j + 1 < parquet[i].size() &&
               parquet[i][j + 1] == '*' &&
               (2 * cell_price > large_cell_price)) {
             j++;
             sum += large_cell_price;
           } else {
            sum += cell_price;
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: is it not bad if I will check `2 * cell_price > large_cell_price` each iteration?

Comment: @rel1x, its better than running `for`loop twice.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way can be:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < parquet.size(); ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < parquet[i].size(); ++j) {
    if (2 * cell_price > large_cell_price) {
        if (parquet[i][j] == '*') {
          if (j + 1 < parquet[i].size() && parquet[i][j + 1] == '*') {
            j++;
            sum += large_cell_price;
          } else {
            sum += cell_price;
          }
        }
    } else {
        if (parquet[i][j] == '*') {
          sum += cell_price;
        }
    }
  }
}
```